# Cannot sync gradle with standalone installation; missing kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

So this is my first attempt to do anything on Android, but because I'm behind a firewall I've tried to set up a local version of the environment, per the Android Studio download site, and have followed their instructions and have the latest build of Android Studio, 3.5.3.

The first problem I solved was the classpath seemed to be using a version of Gradle that wasn't included in the installations.   Now that that has been solved, I'm getting the following errors regarding Kotlin missing (and I can confirm that these files do not exist).

So far, Hello World Fail... not sure why the configs provided all point to libraries that aren't included, but I'm definitely frustrated, and it's a steep learning curve to understand all of the dependencies involved.

Here's the errors when I sync Gradle:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21.
Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/jhladik/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/jhladik/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar
Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.4.0
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.0
```

Comment: Pls try to find missing dependencies here and cache them locally: https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Went to repository and got the .pom and .jar files that AS says are missing, and created the paths as it specified.  Dropped the files in the directory and tested navigation with a cut and paste, so the directory structure is definitely correct, as well as the naming.  Same errors, however, and cleared cache and restarted, too.